# How do I delete the “Apps” bookmark in my bookmark bar on linux?

Tags: google-chrome

The bookmark is can be easily removed on windows. User can right click on it to remove it. How do I remove it on linux?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but the web browser works the same regardless of OS. If you Right Click > Remove under Windows it will work the same on Linux. If you are having issues with this try `Ctrl-Shift-B` (I think) to toggle the bar on and off.

UPDATE: Really not trying to point out the obviously, but just in case please ensure you are ignoring the 'delete' button halfway down your right-click menu and look for the check option 'Show Apps shortcut'. Obviously if this is viable left click to un-check it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works if you click any other bookmark BUT "Apps".

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your right-click menu when you click the Apps Button.

Comment: Same issue here. Right clicking opens no menu at all.